# How do you make a template for a mixed bullet list in XSLT

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

How do I make a template so the following XML...

```
<content>
<bullet>text</bullet>
<bullet>more text</bullet>
o more text
o more text
o more text
<bullet>more text</bullet>
</content>
```

looks like this in html...

```
<li>text</li
<li>more text</li>
o more text
o more text
o more text
<li>more text</li>
```

It's probably simple, but I just end up with...

```
text
more text
o more text
o more text
o more text
more text
<li>text</li>
<li>more text</li>
<li>more text</li>
```

Thank-you for any help.

Comment: Your desired output is not conformant HTML, since <UL> elements can only contain <LI> elements, not raw text. Don't you really want to convert the three `o more text` lines into into sub-bullets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="content">
      <ul><xsl:apply-templates/></ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="bullet">
      <li><xsl:apply-templates/></li>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- processes all *nodes* by copying them, 
             and can be overridden for individual 
             elements, attributes, comments, processing instructions, 
             or text nodes -->

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- replace content with ul -->
    <xsl:template match="content">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- replace bullet with li --> 
    <xsl:template match="bullet">
        <li>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Omit the `select="@*|node()"` attributes, they're somewhere between unnecessary and wrong. The first template can and should be left out altogether, since the default rules for text nodes will get the job done. Output should be designated as HTML. Remove strip-space, it is not necessary.

Comment: @torazaburo Your statements and your answer to this question is that really "unnecessary"...

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want a template that matches everything, and then display output depending on what the input was.  I use `node()` as the template match, then use a `<xsl:when>` tag to determine if I'm working with straight text or the contents of a `<bullet>` node and display accordingly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="node()">
  <xsl:for-each select="node()">

      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="node()">
          <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>

  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can use this tool to test out the stylesheet: http://xslttest.appspot.com/ (unfortunately this app doesn't have a permalink feature).  I get the following output:

```
<li>text</li>

<li>more text</li>
o more text
o more text
o more text

<li>more text</li>
```

Comment: This is BASIC masquerading as XSLT.

Comment: @torazaburo: You are correct, I am an XSLT noob :).  Thanks for your answer, I learned a lot from it.